# How do people encode WEBMs to to increase the end time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a discord video that explains exactly what i mean.
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/288528119525146635/634072701585195038/you.webm
Basicaly the video starts off lasting only 0:02 seconds but as it plays the end time increases all the way up to 1:03 or something. I dont Know how people do this.

Comment: Is that something you want to achieve for a particular reason, or…? Which player are you using?

Answer (score 2):

For webm files, the duration is part of the data included in the file. If you want to change this, open the webm video in a hex editor (i use the hex edit plugin on notepad++), then scroll down to address `00000140`. That row contains the duration data. Specifically address `00000141` to `0000014b`.
`44 89 88 40 be 1b 00 00 00 00 00`
Im not 100% sure but im pretty sure `44 89` is an Element ID identifying this as the duration element. Next, `88` im pretty sure this one is the size of the content. Lastly, we have the actual content, this is what you will want to change to mess with the video length and progress bar. It is a signed 64-bit Double, you can use [binaryconvert](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=052056048048048) to convert the decimal time (in milliseconds) to the hex value you need.

If your still confused, [watch this video by flytech about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxHQ7dW6M2s)

Answer (score 0):

The video simply doesn't signal a length at all (i.e. a length of 0) - this way the length shown by different players can either be zero, how much is buffered, or even the negative length played (totem).

Comment: You've answered "what" but not "how"